# SharePoint 2010 - content-type with large lookup columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, content-type

We have to design a content-type with 20 lookup columns. Again lookup columns are dependent on "Managed Metadata" & "User profile" service etc.

Is it a good idea to design such CT?

If not, then how to approach this situation?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how lookup columns are "dependent" on managed metadata and user profile? Will some columns be managed metadata columns? That should not be a problem. How do the columns depend on the UPS? Please provide more detail.

Comment: Hi Teylyn,'my question was wrong. By mistake I wrote UPS. actually it value from people picker, another one is manage metadata column. I know only 8 column max we can design. But if we need 25 what should be our approach to meet customers expectation?

Comment: I suggest you review your requirements, edit your question and put the real requirements in there. Make sure you use the common terminology and use a spell checker.